# Connecting to remote MySQL from local machine

Tags: mysql, remote-access

Ok so I've read this countless times that under Remote MySQL in your cpanel (I host with namecheap) that you shouldn't add 127.0.0.1 as a host to allow remote connection to your database since it could be a security risk.

However, I wanted to know if there is anyway I can connect to my MySQL database on my hosting server from my local machine.. instead of using the MySQL thing that comes with WAMP since I hate transferring databases back and forth after I develop for a week on my local machine. The data tends to not stay consistent over time and it gets tiring having to drop your database and reupload it with the newest tables.

So I was wondering if there was a way to allow this connection without exploiting a security risk? So I don't have to have two separate databases..? Unless it's safer to keep up with this practice..?

Thank you!

And I know the IP changes often on your machine (a dynamic IP I believe is what it's called) so is there anyway I can have an unlimited connection no matter if the IP changes?

Comment: I can't understand your reference to `127.0.0.1`—that is *always* the local machine, by definition. You need to authorize your public IP address (which is normally your router's address). You suggest you already know how to do that from Cpanel so I'm unsure about what your question is.

Comment: You can't use 127.0.0.1. I mean you can, but that is EVERYONES local machine and it would give access to all those other local developers.. which is a security risk..? And you IP changes on every machine. Like when I go a local restaurant and they have WiFi, my IP will change so I won't be able to access my database unless I add their IP which is not something I would want to do.

Comment: That doesn't give other people access.  It, by definition, only gives *the local machine* access.  My local machine is not the same as your local machine!

Comment: Yours is 127.0.0.1... Everyone's is... So if I gave 127.0.0.1 access, everyone would have access to it. That's what those other articles said..??

Comment: @Peanut Can you link to this article?  Are you concerned about other people on your shared hosting?  What is it set to listen on now?

Comment: Sorry, nope, that's not how TCP/IP works. When you connect to another machine your use a private or public address (depending on the network type), never a loopback address, which is exclusive to self-connections. If such article exists, it must be an April Fools prank.

Comment: Well it was just from other articles I was reading. I didn't save their URLs.. What do you mean set to listen on now?? I guess I'm just confused by this entire thing. So I can just add 127.0.0.1 and then connect with my credentials from my WAMP server?

Comment: No, if your server is listening on 127.0.0.1, you will not be able to connect to it from your development machine without SSH tunneling in (see my answer).  It is generally not a good idea to listen on a public interface (anything *other* than 127.0.0.1).

Comment: `127.0.0.1` means "myself". If you instruct the MySQL server to "allow access from myself" you won't be able to connect from outside, because your home PC is *not* the MySQL server.

Comment: Ok I think I'll just choose the SSH route. xD I'm confused by everything. Sorry. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: You decide, but setting a SSH tunnel requires a complex set-up and you also need a hosting plan that provides the SSH service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why they would say not to add 127.0.0.1 - that's the local machine, which means that people from the outside can't access it.  So you have `skip-networking` turned on and you're connecting through a local UNIX socket?  Are you sure it didn't say not to add anything *other* than 127.0.0.1?

Do you have SSH access?  If so, you can easily use SSH tunneling so that you'll only have to connect locally with a command like
`ssh -L 3307:localhost:3306 -N yoursever.com`
Then you connect locally on your home machine to port 3307 (you can make this 3306 but you said you develop your database locally as well, so in that case you'd need a different port).  Then the packets go through SSH and magically appear at the database, looking as though they had come from the same machine.  The security there is all done by SSH, which is great because it has "secure" right in the name, without opening additional ports (assuming that you have the SSH daemon running)

Comment: Well a lot of people's local machine uses 127.0.0.1.. Right now I just have MYSQL through WAMP and then export that database .sql file and go into my cpanel, drop the tables in the database and import the .sql file.. it gets tiring and throws things off sometimes..
Hmmmm.. if I could access my database locally I would most likely develop the database on the production server so I can just stick to one database. I'm not really familiar with SSH access.. Is there an article on that?